# Is it possible to create overloaded setters for Jackson/POJO mapper?

Tags: serialization, jersey, operator-overloading, deserialization

I  have a class:

```
    @Column(name = "data", nullable = false)
String  data;


public void setData(final String data) {
    this.data = data;
}


public void setDataAsSet(final Set<String> strings) {
    setData(JOINER.join(strings));
}
```

Can Jackson serialize / de-serialize it?
Ideally I would like to (at least) support de-serialization.

I've searched the web and found no clear answer. Some bug reports, and suggestions to @ignore the 'un-necessary' getter / setter, but I want all of them.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't understand. This code doesn't even compile... Not because of '...'

Comment: @opal It's pseudo-code. I have overloaded setters (one with a String object, one with a Set<String>) and getters(one returns a String, the other a set of Strings). Is it supported in Jackson, and if so - how?  Thanks.

Comment: Well. Ok. But it isn't overloading - You have same method names and only different return types. It won't compile. Please edit and paste full sample bean You'd like to map.

Comment: @opal You are right. I'm too tired. Ignore the 'setters'.

Comment: Hm.. To be honest still no idea what You'd like to achieve :/ Maybe a little scenario description? Or full bean You'd like to be created from JSON.

Comment: @opal pasted real code. I want the client to be able to send either comma separated string like: "a,b,b" or a set of Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be possible with writing custom deserializer. Unfortunately have no opportunity to set the env now and try. But in general I don't it's a good idea to send same data as `String` or `Set<String>`. It will result in hard to debug bugs or other unpredictable problems. There should be two separately declared fields or it should always be a collection (in most cases it will probably have single element). Rethink it please.

I still encourage You to rethink the design nevertheless did it:

Bean:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

public class SampleBean {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = SampleDeserializer.class)
    public String data;
}
```

Deserializer:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import static com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken.VALUE_STRING;

public class SampleDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        JsonToken jt = jp.getCurrentToken();
        if (jt == VALUE_STRING) {
            return jp.getValueAsString();
        } else if (jt == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
            return jp.readValueAs(List.class).toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replaceAll("\\s*", "");// joining could be done much better of course
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SampleTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        final String json = "{\"data\":\"2\"}";
        final String json2 = "{\"data\":[\"2\",\"3\"]}";

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        SampleBean sb = om.readValue(json, SampleBean.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("2", sb.data);
        sb = om.readValue(json2, SampleBean.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("2,3", sb.data);
    }
}
```